# enable select template option in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to change the template of post, by default `single.php` is being used but for few post I want to apply different layout, I have created a new template and have placed the following code:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Work Single
* Template Post Type: post, page, product
*/ 
get_header(); ?>
```

But the problem is select option is not available in post edit section, how do I enable this?

Additionally I have custom post type for which I have codes in the `functions.php` is like below:

```
    if ( ! function_exists('people_post_type') ) {

// Register Custom Post Type
function people_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Peoples', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'People', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'People', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'People', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'People Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'People Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Peoples', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New People', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add People', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New People', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit People', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update People', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View People', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Peoples', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search People', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'People', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'People type.', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'view-people','with_front' => true), 
    );
    register_post_type( 'people', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'people_post_type', 0 );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code Looks Good, Just make sure that the template file you have created is stored in the **current** theme folder of the website.

Also, make sure that you specify your custom post name in Template Post Type: your-custom-post-name.

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Work Single
* Template Post Type: post, page, product, your-custom-post-name
*/ 
get_header(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by `specify your custom post name in Template Post Type: your-custom-post-name` can you please explain this?

Comment: As you have said you have custom post type defined in functions.php ,so if you want to use the template in your custom post type you have to define your custom post name in "Template Post Type" of your template.

Comment: Alright, so in `functions.php` I have the name defined : `'name'                  => _x( 'Peoples', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),` then in the template I have created should have the name defined like this `Template Post Type:text_domain` correct?

Comment: Please update your functions.php file in your question

Comment: Add Template Post Type: post, page, product, people

Comment: Thanks for quick answer on this. Its working perfectly.